# how to define angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker timezone?

Tags: angularjs, timezone, datetimepicker, utc

I am evaluating [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker), is there a way to set the timezone for the component so the dates on the screen would appear in some custom timezone like UTC? E.g. when I am in GMT+3 and I click on the UI button for "Aug 13 2PM", and output the following:

```
From: {{date.date}}<br>
From: {{date.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}
```

The output will be 3 hours apart, where the local time corresponds to the button in the UI, meaning that on the UI, I see local times - not UTC time. For example:

```
From: "2015-08-13T11:00:00.000Z"
From: 2015-08-13 14:00
```

I also tried running moment().utcOffset(0) immediately after loading moment.js, it didn't help.

How do I set the component to show the UI in a custom timezone?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to set the timezone, it always uses the timezone of the browser.

If you just need utc dates (i.e. milliseconds), there is a new modelType setting that allows you to always work in UTC.